# Debug custom scheme in XCode issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have created a custom scheme in Xcode, which loads a separate plist file and I use this build for testing the application. I've removed the Archive option from the build, so that I do not accidentally publish this development version.

My issue is that I cannot really debug this build and I am not sure why. While the default build works fine in the Xcode debugger, my scheme does not. The breakpoints work, but single stepping fails and print object commands also fail with unrecognized variable errors.

It does look like maybe some option would be needed to add debug symbols or so, but I can't find that after having tried a few things in the Xcode project options. Going back to the default Debug build is not convenient, because my new scheme has different plist options, used for testing. Btw, my new scheme was cloned from the debug one when I first made it.

Any ideas how to fix that ?

Comment: Turn off Optimizations.

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) Please make it an answer if you like and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off optimizations will allow you to debug the application even if in Release-Mode. Optimizations strip the executable and that is why you cannot debug the variables.